# How to change placeholder color using button in ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to change placeholder color in my text input in ionic 3. Here is my code

in main.html

```
<ion-input class="changeColor" placeholder="test" type="tel"></ion-input>
```

main.scss

```
.changeColor::-moz-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.changeColor:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.changeColor::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-indent: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

thanks for reading my problem, I want to know the reason why this placeholder not changing the color.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried this :

```
ion-input{
  input::placeholder {
    color:red!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: i know that's will work. i want create one class to make the placeholder color change. but when i do it doesn't work

Comment: please check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder in order to apply css for place holder this is the best practice and also i don't think there is another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the place holder color by overriding the ionic Sass variable. Check this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/). You can assign $text-input-placeholder-color variable to the color you want.